# Trying to call a PHP CLI script from a web script causes Apache to spawn multiple child processes

Tags: php, apache, command-line-interface

Having read loads of threads about calling a long-running PHP CLI script from a web script, and the best way to daemonize the CLI script, I have hit an insoluble problem with the way Apache handles the CLI script.
According to [this blog post](http://symcbean.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/php-and-long-running-processes.html), the best option is to do something like :

```
print `echo /usr/bin/php -q longThing.php | at now`;
```

When I do this on my local CentOS 7/PHP 7/Apache 2.4.6 VM, it works like a charm, however, the identical code on my production server Centos 6.8/PHP 7/Apache 2.4.25 (cPanel) causes Apache to spawn 100s of child processes, rapidly exhausting the CPU and memory resources, requiring a reboot to fix. Even if I quickly kill the PHP CLI process, Apache has already got itself into some kind of loop. My understanding was that by using the suggested code above, you disassociated Apache from the CLI process, but clearly not.
Can anyone point me toward what is going wrong ? I can post the actual code and more details of my production server if needed.
Thanks

Comment: Just a note: Why using `-q` here, you add no parameters?

Comment: I would do this `php longThing.php >> /path/to/log/log.log 2>&1 &` that pushes the job into the background and log all into a logfile

Comment: Use -q as suggested by blog post to disocciate the web script from the apache process that called it. The intent is to daemonize the cli script so that apache (a) doesn't spawn it as a child process and (b) the cli script will survive an apache restart.

Comment: The blog post you linked, which is 7 years old, is wrong. If for whatever reason you need to do something in the background. you'd use some sort of job server - granted, this isn't always possible. So, the best way would be to have your Apache "talk" to PHP via FastCGI, not via `mod_php`. Then you can utilize a great function called `fastcgi_finish_request();` which lets you send output to web server and then continue doing your long task in the background.

Comment: @Grindlay `-q` after `php` stays for use next parts as args, so `php -q test.php foo bar` will have in php in `$argsv` this `array('test.php','foo','bar')`.

Comment: @Mjh I referred to it as it seemed  to have a lot of supporting comments but I take your point, it is probably out of date. I don't think the problem is necessarily the way the CLI script is called/daemonized though - I suspect it is the way that different Apache implementations (threaded/FastCGI etc) handle things like exec() and shell_exec() in web scripts. Trying to work out why it works on one machine and not another (almost identical) machine.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

php file called xyz.php

```
<?php
shell_exec('php -r "sleep(20);" >> /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

then run under command line

```
php xyz.php
```

And it is equal behavior if you call it from an browser.

`xyz.php` will finish and not wait 20 seconds.